# Unable to assign a Session variable value from within a Class file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I am getting this error trying to assign a session value from within a Class file in VB, VS2012.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have tried both lines of code below and get the same error.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("dbTblName") = dbTblName

HttpContext.Current.Session("dbTblName") = dbTblName
```

The dbTblName variable is populated with a string value. the function class is called from a call into a web service.

Ah I think I am seeing it, there is no http here. Duh!

Comment: From what class are you calling from?  can you include that?  And this is a class that an ASp.NET page is using?  It's not an out of band request?

Comment: Not even calling it yet, it errors on the assignment. It will not set the session value. It is a Public Class inside a Friend function, within a Try Catch block.

Comment: I would guess that HttpContext.Current  is null. You would have to show some more code to validate this.

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("dbTblName") Referenced object has a value of 'Nothing'. Object

Comment: I trapped that in the Watch. Is there a fix here, what am I doing wrong? I have never seen this happen before. Also that is triggered from a call into a web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its most likely because the HttpContext object which the Session belongs to is not accessible to you within this scope or context at the time of assignment.

Why not check if the HttpContext is available before assigning it. However if you can provide more information with regards to the class and where you are calling it then better help can be provided

UPDATE:

If you are calling this within a service a method attribute might be needed on the service object to enable the session object as this is not enabled by default:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void CallingMethod()
{

}
```

Comment: Updated comments above.

Comment: Figures, if had I looked at the other services I would have seen a similar setting, I had coded some time ago. Not good on my part, but totally awesome on yours. I knew this was easy and hit myself when I saw your answer. Just brain dead today I guess!!! Thanks again!!!

Comment: @htm11h happens to everyone, glad I could help out.